# Qt Browser cannot open Unity WebGL build

Tags: qt, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I started testing around with the QT nano browser example. We're researching the possibility to use this for our Unity WebGL project.

Anyway, So I download QT creator, and go to the nano browser example. Everything I try to load in works, except our WebGL project(other unity webGL projects work).

I'm not sure in how far I can share the links to our project here, but here is the error log I receive when loading it without our url's.

[image]

So essentially what it does it get in an endless loop trying to load in the Unity build. It just keeps trying. We're using Unity 2019.2 if that matters. Our WebGL build works in Chrome, Firefox etc etc.

Any clue/direction for me to look? I can't find much myself and have no clue where these errors are coming from. 1 time I actually got into my WebGL build but then after about 10 seconds it threw me out and restarted trying to load in. Could not reproduce that as it just worked 1 time magically.

Any help is appreciated. If you need more info let me know, I will gladly deliver it.